# ASP.NET: Menu Control in Master Page fails to use CSS styles

Tags: asp.net, css

I am developing ASP.NET web application for my company. I am using the Windows Authentication since this web application will be only used inside the company.

I defined the menu/ navigation bar inside the site.master page as a list in (HTML ul and li) format. Also, I have a special CSS for this menu which is the following:

```
/* TOPNAV */
.topnav { padding:0; margin:0; width:966px; height:53px; background: url(images/bg_menu.gif) top repeat-x; }


/* level 0 */
.topnav ul { padding:0; margin:0 30px 0 0; list-style:none; border:0; float: left; }
.topnav ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0; border-right:1px solid #303030; border-left:1px solid #0a0a0a; }
.topnav ul li a { float:left; margin:0 1px 0 0; padding:17px 47px; color:#fff; font:normal 14px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; text-decoration:none; }
.topnav ul li.current_page_item { }     
.topnav ul li.current_page_item a,
.topnav ul li a.a_hover_main { color:#fff; background-color:#0f0f0f;}                       /* on hover */


/* level 1 */
.topnav ul li ul { padding:0; top:52px; left:-2px; height:auto; color:#a8a7a7; background-color:#0f0f0f; border-bottom:none;}           
.topnav ul li ul li { margin:0; padding:0; background:none; border-bottom:1px solid #010101;}
```

Because for the Admin, I want him to see the same menu bar but with more items. My friend told me that I can do this by implementing the menu using Menu Control. I created the site navigation map and I put the menu control in the master page, but the problem now is how to use the above CSS file with the Menu Control.

So how can I do that? Please provide me with example (if any)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set this option inside menu controller:

CssClass="topnav"

Comment: I tried it. This option gave me only the background of the menu bar what about the padding, margin, and the second level of the menu as you see in the CSS code above?

Comment: if something else doesnt work it means it gets reset somewhere (you have another ul , ul li CSS)